# SQL Server 2012: Server Protocols show login trials

Tags: sql-server

We are running a SQL Server Express instance on a VM-Server in the cloud.
Recently I had a look into Server protocols and found thousands of protocols crated permanently stating:

Error 18456:
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occured while evaluating the password (CLIENT:222.240.205.101)

Many different usernames have been passed that way (such as 'mssqla', 'kisadmin', etc.) and the client-ips points to China and India!!
What does this mean??

Further I find in these protocols many stating
"Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLSERVEREXPRESSTempDB'"

and further 
"Starting up database 'AdventureWorks2012'" which does not even exist on that server.

Is someone trying to hack the server?
Any preventions we can do against these trials?

Thanks your help
Michael

Comment: Polling for weak and stupid credentials such as admin/admin. There is not much you can do from SQL Server perspective and if you change the default port, someone will eventually find it. A hardware solution can reduce the clutter.

Comment: It is common and expected that script kiddies will knock on your door when the box is exposed to the public internet. But I don't know what you mean by "protocols stating starting up database...". If you see those messages in the SQL Server error log, the databses are defined to SQL Server (but may be invalid).

Comment: I think @DanGuzman touched on an important point. Your SQL Server should be closed to the outside world unless you have a very good reason for opening it up.

Comment: Well, I connected the SQL database on the internet to my local mssms for easier development.  I will close the port when I move everything on that VM-Server and connect then by RDP. @DanGuzman: Starting up database xyz is strange because as I said AdventureWorks2012 does not exist, the ReportSErver$SQLSERVEREXPRESSTempDB exists, but I never touched it and WHY are there many protocol entries that those databases are starting up..?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by protocol entries? Do you mean SQL Server error log entries? In the case the the error log, I would expect all those databases listed with query `SELECT name FROM sys.databases;`.

Comment: No, with entries I mean protocols. Whatever an entry is called which leads to a protocol (I am no native speaker...I hope you understand me anyway).

Comment: @mak, the "starting up database" messages are normal in the SQL Server error log (SSMS Management-->SQL Server Logs) 1) when SQL Server starts and 2) when a closed database is opened. I am concerned because #2 only happens after successful authentication, AFAIL. Do you see AdventureWorks2012 listed with `SELECT name FROM sys.databases;`?